# Is it fine to use my domain model as DTO (Entity Framework Core)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ddd, entity-framework-core

I was reading about anemic data models and rich domain models in DDD. I don't want to follow DDD completely but take rather pragmatic approach and just take some concepts out of it because clean ddd seems like an overkill. What I'm building is Web API (using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core).

I don't want to maintain separate DTOs just for serializing and deserializing my models.

And I want to make most of the things like service layer and my controllers generic. Because it's mostly CRUD and logic is repeating - a lot of boilerplate.

I'm not planning to use any other ORM other than EF Core.

EF Core allows mapping to backing fields:

https://ardalis.com/encapsulated-collections-in-entity-framework-core
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/mt842503.aspx

Is it fine if I will design my models like this and at the same time use them as my DTOs for serialization and deserialization?

```
public class Player
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [NotMapped, Required]
    public PlayerInfo ActiveInfo { get; set; } // setter must be public to allow deserialization (or use custom resolver for json net)

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<PlayerInfo> PlayerInfos { get; set; } = new HashSet<PlayerInfo>();

    private Player()
    {
    }

    public Player(PlayerInfo info)
    {
        info.IsActive = true;
        PlayerInfos.Add(info);
    }

    public void SetActiveInfo(PlayerInfo playerInfo)
    {
        var currentlyActiveInfo = PlayerInfos.SingleOrDefault(info => info.IsActive);
        if (currentlyActiveInfo != null)
        {
            currentlyActiveInfo.IsActive = false;
        }
        playerInfo.IsActive = true;
        PlayerInfos.Add(playerInfo);

        ActiveInfo = playerInfo;
    }
}
```

This is controller:

```
public class PlayerController
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext { get; set; }
    private readonly DbSet<Player> _players { get; set; }

    public PlayerController(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _players = dbContext.Set<Player>();
    }

    // Create new player
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<Player> Post([FromBody] Player player)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           //Handle validation error
        }
        // No service layer for the sake of simplicity.
        player.SetActiveInfo(player.ActiveInfo); // will use _activeInfo
        _players.Add(player); // begins tracking entity 
        if (_dbContext.Save() == 0)
        {
            // handle error

        }
        return player;
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea of CodeReview is to review *working code*. I doubt this is actually working because I don't see any way to get `_playerInfos` loaded in EF core. Is this actually working as intended? If not, this question belongs on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I changed it to property. The question is not primarily focused on that. Thanks for your comment anyway :)

Comment: Now `_playerInfos` is invalid in `SetActiveInfo`. But it's always problematic to change code significantly while it's under review, because even when it's a property I have some reservations, but obviously not the same ones. Maybe you get away with it in this case because the current answer is generic enough to cover both situations.

Comment: @GertArnold I guess so. I was editing in hurry and I didn't notice. Well, I must admit you're hell of a reviewer ;) But it just didn't seem like a good fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was reading about anemic data models and rich domain models in DDD. I don't want to follow DDD completely but take rather pragmatic approach and just take some concepts out of it because clean ddd seems like an overkill.
>
> I don't want to maintain separate DTOs just for serializing and deserializing my models.

I'm similarly pragmatic as you, and I agree with you in this situation.

**KISS** (keep it simple & stupid) applies here. If your application is not sufficiently large, a DTO layer abstraction is not necessary.

I have several colleagues who would disagree with this, this is an open discussion topic. Personally, I disagree with blindly implementing things just because it was needed in other projects. Before I implement something, I need to justify its existence in the current project.

> I'm not planning to use any other ORM other than EF Core.

It's not so much about what you **plan** to use, but rather the chance of this changing in the future, and how prepared you want to be when it turns out you have to change it.

---

> Is it fine if I will design my models like this and at the same time use them as my DTOs for serialization and deserialization?

Yes, as long as you're okay with the tighter coupling and don't start violating SRP by loading everything into your entity classes.

However, that is a separate discussion from whether or not you should use DTOs. You could just as well violate SRP on your DTO class.

Comment: When would I violate SRP on my entity model?

Comment: If the logic in my domain model operates only on those model's properties/fields - does this violate it?

Comment: I also think that even when application is large, complexity grows with it when using DTOs. There's just more to maintain and I think it would be better to name it differently than DTO. Sometimes when you add new property you have to add it to DTO too, and if you don't use some auto mapper you have to maintain the mapping too, or perhaps reconfigure auto mapper.

Comment: Something like PlayerResource, or PlayerRequest, PlayerResponse would be nicer for eyes.

Comment: @Konrad: For example, adding additional properties that do not map to the entity (in DB), e.g. `public string FullName { get { return $"{FirstName} {LastName}"; } }` That should be done either on a DTO class; or implemented by the consumer of your webservice (since the backend doesn't need the property).

Comment: @Konrad: Yes, DTOs are more  work. But note the intention of using DTOs, it's not implemented to decrease the lines of code (it's an **extra** layer which brings **extra** work with it), but rather to allow for loose coupling between layers so that they can easily be swapped for another component.

Comment: could you give some example of situation when I would want to swap them for another component?

Comment: I can't think of one.

Comment: @Konrad: Imagine if you sell your application, but some customers want to use an SQL database, others want to use a NoSQL database, and others want to use an XML file storage. With tight coupling, you'd need to develop 3 variants of the same codebase. With loose coupling, you develop one codebase with an easily swappable data layer (you still have three datalayer projects, but only one web service project).

Comment: @Konrad: Think of it this way: when you buy a desktop PC, you get to pick which components you put in it. You may want a powerful graphics card, someone else might not. Now imagine if your motherboard was designed for a specific graphics card because the developers never expected anyone to want to use a different graphics card. That's essentially what you're now deciding: "no one who uses my application will ever want to use anything other than EF Core".

Comment: I like your example. Do you know of any good code example in C# of such easily swappable data layer?

Comment: How should I model my data to make it swappable and not dependent upon EF Core?

Comment: @Konrad: The discussion is running a bit too broad now. Basically, separate your entities (classes) from your data layer. Regardless of how you store the data (SQL, NoSQL, XML), you'll always want to use a `Player` class. Alternatively, DTOs allow you to have data-layer specific entity classes, which then all map to the same DTO class. This means that the consumer of your web service doesn't need to change its behavior based on which storage the backend is using.

Comment: Right, thanks :D That clarified a lot of things

Answer (score 2):

As I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18113611/861716), the EF model is primarily a data layer. Its classes *may* be suited for other roles, but their primary responsibility should always be: smooth data access.

Your question is about combining three possible roles an EF model class could play:

1. A property bag that communicates data back and forth between the database and object-oriented code. That's obviously it's primary role.
2. A DDD class that encapsulates business logic, i.e. data and methods working on them (the OO principle).
3. A DTO class that communicates between some client (UI or B2B) and the business logic.

It may be perfectly valid to combine role 1 with one or both of the other roles, as long as role 1 isn't compromised in any way. Sometimes that's a thin line, but generally the Single Responsibility Principe is a good touchstone.

I can be short about combining role 1 and 3. This may be valid in simple CRUD functions, although I don't like the dependency on Json.Net in a data layer class. And who says that in each use case the same properties should be ignored? It's generally preferred to use dedicated DTOs for client traffic.

The DDD role is tougher to judge. Let me focus on your example.

The method...

> ```
> public void SetActiveInfo(PlayerInfo playerInfo)
> {
>     var currentlyActiveInfo = PlayerInfos.SingleOrDefault(info => fo.IsActive);
>     if (currentlyActiveInfo != null)
>     {
>         currentlyActiveInfo.IsActive = false;
>     }
>     playerInfo.IsActive = true;
>     PlayerInfos.Add(playerInfo);
>     ActiveInfo = playerInfo;
> }
> ```

...relies on `PlayerInfos` to have been loaded. If they aren't you have to rely on *lazy loading*. Lazy loading is supported in EF-core [since version 2.1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading) (currently in pre-release). For lazy loading the context must be active (not disposed) when the collection is accessed.

So there's a couple of things that may go wrong here:

1. `PlayerInfos` isn't loaded and lazy loading isn't enabled: the currently active record isn't deactivated and you end up having two active records without even noticing it.
2. `PlayerInfos` isn't loaded, lazy loading is enabled, but the context is disposed. Now an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown, like:

   > An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'PlayerInfos' on entity type 'PlayerProxy_3' after the associated DbContext was disposed.

To prevent these errors you'd want to ensure that whenever `SetActiveInfo` is to be executed `PlayerInfos` is eagerly loaded (using `Include`). Two options:

1. Since it may not always be clear if the program control flow will end up calling the method it may seem sensible to load the collection always. But that would require `Include` any old time `Player`s are loaded, even when they're not needed.
2. Load `PlayerInfos` right before `SetActiveInfo` is going to be called (if possible).

Where's the DDD going here? For the first option the code always needs to know that `Player` must have loaded `PlayerInfos` and there may not be a single source of players: they may get loaded from the `DbSet` but also in `Includes` and navigation properties.

The second option is even worse: the caller is made responsible for `Player`'s proper state.

In DDD you'd use a class that is guaranteed to have all data it requires to execute its methods properly. Objects of this class will be created solely by a factory that ensures their integrity. It's always safe to call their methods ([Tell, don't ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)).

So, to summarize, it may be possible to equip EF classes for executing business logic. It mainly depends on the extend to which it can be guaranteed that the data layer produces entities in the proper state.

Comment: I couldn't help answering, even after the accepted answer. I love the subject :)

Comment: "In DDD you'd use a class that is guaranteed to have all data it requires to execute its methods properly" - does it apply if `PlayerInfos` is eager loaded?

Comment: It applies if  you can count on`PlayerInfos` to be loaded always. It's the *guaranteed* integrity that counts. I don't think it's possible to give this assurance with an EF entity, also because EF doesn't support eager loading by configuration (like join fetch in NHibernate).

Comment: I think guaranteed integrity depends on implementation. If I implement it in my logic to fetch PlayerInfos then it's guaranteed to exist.

Comment: Nothing comes from nowhere

Comment: Sure, if you can guarantee it, for example by having a single point of origin for Players, it's OK.